# Grab the server's return value after uploading a file in Flash

Tags: flash, upload, response, filereference

After uploading a file to a web server using ActionScript 2.0's `FileReference` class, how do I retrieve the server's response?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in the past, but I can't remember off hand how I did it and I don't have access to my old source code.

Here's a link I found, hope it helps.  In the meantime, let me see if I can get a copy of my old code.

http://www.actionscripts.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=157390